# handling dynamo db read and write units

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using dynamo db as back end database in my project, I am storing items in the table with each of size 80 Kb or more(contains nested JSON), and my partition key is a unique valued column(unique for each item). Now i want to perform pagination on this table i.e., my UI will provide(start-Integer,  limit-Integer and type-2 string constants) and my API should retrieve the items from dynamo db based on the provided input query parameters from UI. I am using SCAN method from boto3 (python SDK) but this scan is reading all the items from my table prior to considering my filters and causing  provision throughput error, but I cannot afford to either increase my table's throughput or opt table auto-scaling. Is there any way how my problem can be solved? Please give your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a [limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Limit) set on your `scan` call? If not, DynamoDB will return you 1MB of data by default. You could try using `limit` and some kind of sleep or delay in your code, so that you process your table at a slower rate and stay within your provisioned read capacity. If you do this, you'll have to use the [LastEvaluatedKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination) returned to you to page through your table.

Keep in mind that just to read a single one of your 80kb items, you'll be using [10 read capacity units](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CapacityUnitCalculations.html), and perhaps more if your items are larger.